# comparing multiple items in a list against one number then have multiple prints

Tags: python

I have a long list of numbers and I want to compare them all to 0 at the same time and if they are greater, to print out along with another long list. my problem is, I don't know how to do that and I don't want to spend all night typing the same couple lines of code 90 times. This is what I have:

`if nums[n]>0:
  print(nums[n]'='templist[n])
else:
    print('')`

and this is what I want it to say:

`if nums[1-90]>0:
  print(nums[1-90]'='templist[1-90])
else:
    print('')`

Comment: I figure it should use a while loop, but I'm having trouble implementing that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop with a range to go through index 1 - 90 (this will miss index 0):

```
for i in range(1, 91):
  if nums[i] > 0:
    print(str(nums[i]) + '=' + str(templist[i]))
  else:
    print('')
```

if you want to go through every item in the list, you can use enumerate which give you each item and its index:

```
for (i, v) in enumerate(nums):
  if v > 0:
    print(str(v) + '=' + str(templist[i]))
  else:
    print('')
```